# display UNCLAIMED for onboard GPU Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution, gpu-driver

I am using the onboard graphics of the motherboard "Gigabyte Gaming X670 X AX" and I have installed a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (also tried 20.04 LTS). On startup the screen resolution is stuck at 1024x768 and in settings it says **unknown display**.

Here are the specs of the motherboard: https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/X670-GAMING-X-AX-rev-10/sp#sp

Here are some details:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
14:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 164e (rev c1)
```

and

```
$ sudo lshw -C video
 *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:14:00.0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:fce0000000-fcefffffff memory:fcf0000000-fcf01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcd00000-fcd7ffff
```

EDIT:
Here is more information:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i iomm
[    0.399302] iommu: Default domain type: Translated 
[    0.399302] iommu: DMA domain TLB invalidation policy: lazy mode
```

EDIT:
More info about my CPU / integrated graphics card:

- AMD Ryzen™ 9 7950X Desktop Processors
- Graphics Model AMD Radeon™ Graphics

Comment: For a long shot `sudo dmesg | grep -i grep -i iomm`

Comment: @nobody I have added the output above

Comment: No wrong idea from me.

Answer (score 0):

The question asked by **Leevi** (23 Jan 2023) requests an explanation of **why** the display issues happened and **possible steps** to either avoid the issue or change the resolution after install.

Supplied below is an explanation for one example which creates the same resolution issue. A fix is then documented which allowed a resolution change in the example.

The example.
A display resolution problem occurred after install of ubuntu 22.10 Mate on an external USB 3.0 dock with Crucial 500GB SATA ssd. The host that did the install was ASROCK z97, some 4-5 years old, Intel hardware i7 cpu, onboard Intel graphics output via Display Port to a Lenovo 32" LCD display, no PCIE video card installed.

The key to why there were display problems on other hosts was the monitor during install: Lenovo 32" at resolution 2560x1440. Boot of the docked SSD on a laptop host (1366x768 max resolution) looked normal, except the display was locked at 640x480. This resolution pushed icons and top line Mate menu bar off screen. The control panel app **Displays** would not accept any changes and it showed **Unknown** for the monitor type. **Xrandr** similarly was ineffective to set the resolution. Advice to create a new xorg.conf also failed to solve the resolution issue.

**The fix**: plug the docked SSD back into the original Asrock host, boot, then change the resolution in control panel app "**Displays**". Reboot on other hosts to see what happened: the display was correct and app "**Displays**" had the correct information about the monitor.

Leevi's hardware information does not document the monitor brand, size and max resolution. The above example suggests that xorg software might be involved in the resolution issue.

The title contains the word UNCLAIMED while the text below cites display UNKNOWN. Perhaps the title should be edited.